# GtkGlArea in Gtk+ 3.0: undefined reference

Tags: c, opengl, gtk, gtk3

GtkGlArea is listed in [the Widget Gallery](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch03.html) of Gtk+3.0. There is [official documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGLArea.html) for it, which states that I only have to include `gtk/gtk.h` to use the desired widget.

But I can't find any OpenGl mentions among header files of gtk+-3.0 package. And of course, I can't call any of the `gtk_gl_area_*` functions without stumbling upon `undefined reference` error.

Is GtkGlArea not available in Gtk+ 3.0? If so, why is it showcased on the official website?

If it is available, how can I use it in my C project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GtkGLArea was added in GTK+ 3.16. If you look at [the documentation page for GtkGLArea](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGLArea.html), you will see

> Since: 3.16

under `gtk_gl_area_new()`.

If you are running GTK+ 3.14 or lower, you do not have access to GtkGLArea. Your distribution can tell you which version you have installed. If your distribution does offer a newer version, then you will need to install it. (The current version as of this writing is GTK+ 3.18.)

If you don't have GTK+ 3.16 or newer, and need to stay with the version of your distribution that you use, you have a few options:

- find someone else's OpenGL widget; [here's one](https://github.com/GNOME/gtkglarea) [and here's another](https://github.com/andrepiske/tegtkgl)
- use [jhbuild](https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/stable/introduction.html.en) to install a local version of a newer GTK+ version and use that to develop
- use a virtual machine with a newer distro to develop

**EDIT**: You can also see documentation for the specific version of GTK+ you need to target by choosing a version from [this list](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/). (The same applies to the other documentation sets on developer.gnome.org.) If backward compatibility is your thing, you should also look into [the `GDK_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` and `GDK_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` macros](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-General.html).

Comment: Thank you! I do have 3.14 installed on my system.